# What is the better way to set the tail while processing a queue implemented by the array in Python?

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to create a queue implemented by the array(Python 2.7). However in some operations, I face with two choices :

```
self.__tail += 1
if self.__tail == len(self.__array):
    self.__tail = 0
self.__count += 1
```

and:

```
self.__tail = (self.__tail+1) % len(self.__array)
self.__count += 1
```

Which is the better one? and What is the pythonic way you think? ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is fine, simple, and Pythonic.  The second way might be preferred by C programmers, but probably offers no improvement in performance in Python.

Comment: I'd rather say that the second way is more of a convention when dealing with cyclic iteration over an array.

Comment: I am agree with your point of view. C might influence me. Is the second one  simple and easy in some circumstances?

Comment: @Octavian: Yes, in C.